# MyBatis API RowBounds Class does full scan of the DB?

Tags: mybatis

When the Class RowBounds in MyBatis API gets data from DB, does it do full scan and then cut the row that is set up by limit and offset parameters? or does it only get the data bound?

Answer (score 1):

If the SQL query contains `offset` and  `limit`/`fetch first n rows only` then the resultset will return only data within bounds. Bounds are applied on DB side. `OFFSET 10000 LIMIT 20` will produces a (maximum) 20 records resultset.

This is likely what you need.

Rowbound does not alter the SQL query and operates independently. Mybatis works with whole Resultset returned by the DB.
e.g.: `RowBounds(10000, 20)` will skip first 10000 records of the resultset, then fetch 20 records and stop. But the result size may be MAX_INT.

Answer (score 0):

It does retrieve full data from database however return only the requested number of records into the program. So, no worries for OutOfMemory but query will take long on database side.

Hibernate and Eclipselink, on the other hand pass on the given limit count onto the database and retrieves only required number of records from database. Hibernate achieves this by using database vendor specific SQL construct in its generated SQL. Ex - LIMIT clause in MS-SQL, Rownum for Oracle.

If you want to achieve the same in mybatis, you need to use these constructs yourselves.
It is easy and you can use mybatis conditions to make the SQL specific to any database.